# Leftover stacks after change of stack key

Tags: javascript, dc.js

I'm building a dashboard using DC. I have dynamic data that I need to update the charts with arbitrarily. I am able to update a heatmap and scatter plot fine, but if I try to update a stacked bar chart, I run into some interesting errors...

You can see in the pre update that the initial rendering is fine:

[image: pre update]

I have controls to change the x axis, y axis, and color (stack by).

The problem I run into you can see in the post update:

[image: post update]

I have changed the `stackBy` key and the chart updates, but there are left over stacks from the [pre update](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j4FJy.png).

When the user selects a different variable, this is the code that I call:

```
// Rebuild the dimension if we changed x axis
const dim = cf.cf.dimension((item) => item[config.metric]);
// Set new dimension
this.chart.dimension(dim);
// Update the stacks
this.setStacks(dim, this.chart);
```

```
setStacks(dim, chart) {
    // Build group with custom reduce function
    const { group, stackKeys, sel_stack } = stack(dim, this.config.stackBy);

    // Create the first group from the first key
    chart.group(
      group,
      stackKeys[0],
      sel_stack(stackKeys[0], "y")
    );
    // Add all other stacks
    for (let i = 1; i < stackKeys.length; i++) {
      chart.stack(
        group,
        stackKeys[i],
        sel_stack(stackKeys[i], "y")
      );
    }
  }
```

```
// Create the stacks using the dimension and the stackKey
// After the first update stackKey === "operator" (the same as the user input)
const stack = (dim, stackKey) => {

  // Build group with custom reduce
  const group = dim.group().reduce(
    (p, v) => {
      if (!p[v[stackKey]]) {
        p[v[stackKey]] = {
          "y": 0,
        };
      }
      p[v[stackKey]]["y"]++;
      return p;
    },
    (p, v) => {
      if (!p[v[stackKey]]) {
        p[v[stackKey]] = {
          "y": 0,
       
        };
      }
      p[v[stackKey]]["y"]--;
      return p;
    },
    () => {
      return {};
    }
  );

  const sel_stack = (valuekey, metricKey) => {
    return (d) => {
      return d.value[valuekey] ? d.value[valuekey][metricKey] : 0;
    };
  };
  // Get all the stack keys
  const arr = _.flatten(
    group.all().map((group) => {
      return Object.keys(group.value);
    })
  );
  const stackKeys = Array.from(new Set(arr));

  return { group, stackKeys, sel_stack };
};
```

I've gone through the debugger and investigated the newly generated group, and the old stacks (the red and purple ones) don't exist in the new group. I can't figure out why they are showing up when I reset the groups and stacks in the update method.

Pre update:

```
{
    "key": 9,
    "value": {
        "Local": {
            "y": 8,
           
        },
        "General": {
            "y": 13,
           
        },
        "State": {
            "y": 4,
           
        },
        "County": {
            "y": 7,
        }
    }
}
```

Post update:

```
{
    "key": 9,
    "value": {
        "salesdemo": {
            "y": 18,
        },
        "SuperUser": {
            "y": 14, 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you rendering or redrawing the chart after changing the stacks? I can't find the specific issue, but I see a mention in [this issue](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/issues/1039) that the stack mixin can't add/remove stacks on a redraw.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yes I was calling `redraw`. Calling `render` after the updates seems to work, and it still keeps my filters selected